# Reset Gitlab Project to Repository Content

Tags: gitlab

I had some unwanted files in a repo which is going open-source soon. I removed the files using git-filter-branch. I noticed the project size in Gitlab growing with every such removal. Some research suggested that Gitlab has another backup layer, where the data is still in the project, which can be accessed by exporting the project.

Is there a way to just reset the Gitlab storage to what the repo actually contains when being cloned?
I'd much prefer not to do these operations again on the project file, since it is prone to data loss.

Comment: Did you check here if it is something that covers your needs? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee//////user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html#purge-files-from-gitlab-storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found in the end is to just create a blank new project, add that to your git remotes and then push to it.

You will have to manually carry over your Issues and probably some other stuff as well. Note that issues can be exported and imported as well, but they loose their comments in the process.

Comment: I'm also trying to find a solution to this. The solution here is more like a last resort. I hope there is a better way than having to make a completely new repo.